# Trying to import excel file(all sheets) into my database

Tags: python, pandas

My main function:

```
dfs = pd.read_excel('sample501.xlsx', sheet_name=None)
d = {k: v[['SR_NO', 'NTN', 'NAME']].values.tolist()
        for k, v in  pd.read_excel('sample501.xlsx', sheet_name=None).items()}

#for test sheetnames
print (dfs.keys())

d = {}
for k, v in dfs.items():
    columns = ['SR_NO', 'NTN', 'NAME']
    df_data = v[columns]
    records = df_data.values.tolist()
    d[k] = records
```

OUTPUT:
dict_keys(['Sheet1', 'Sheet2', 'Sheet3'])
As i said it is reading all 3 sheets but in database only last sheet data is written

Comment: show us the code when you dave data into database

Comment: Looks like you are not exactly looping through a df that has all sheets.

Comment: - sql_insert = '''
    INSERT INTO eg201
    VALUES (?, ?, ?)
'''
try:
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.executemany(sql_insert, d[k])
    cursor.commit();